# Boltzmann brain vs Actual universe probability actual calculations

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, cosmology, universe

I have been reading lots of physics lately about how universe came into being. One idea is that universe is long gone (thermal death) and it might not exist the way I feel it and I am a sequence of [Boltzmann brains](https://plus.maths.org/content/dreaming-dream) fluctuating into existence over incredibly long amounts of time which makes me experience my past and present, and the brains that will be quantum fluctuated will be my future.

The likelihood of universe that we know [fluctuating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_fluctuation) into existence is much less likely due to the size of fluctuation needed. But then I think of calculating probability of universe fluctuating once (and then evolving the way we all know) against many [Boltsmann brain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_brain) fluctuating to represent my lifetime I have to think of the size of a brain.

What sort of Boltsmann brain am I? I don't necessarily have to be human brain I could be software that fluctuates on a microchip and every-time I fluctuate I can be a different kind of brain. Has anyone done any sort of calculations that I could look at what size of fluctuation did they use to compare probabilities.

I have read quite a few articles [that claim that we are likely to be Boltzmann brain](https://plus.maths.org/content/dreaming-dream) but couldn't find any actual math done, I would be surprised if there is no article with calculations on the web.

Comment: Don't try crossing the long-gone highway on your long-gone feet in your still existing Boltzman brain. It may just happen that a long gone car will hit you and kill you... Just my two cents in response to more than slightly-off center speculations about the nature of the universe.

Comment: @CuriousOne It would be a shame to die from that.

Comment: Yes, it would be. :-)

Comment: More on [Boltzmann brains](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+boltzmann+brain*).

Comment: I would appreciate if people voting to close would leave comments on which part of question they find confusing, and how I could improve. Thanks.

Comment: I believe it is pretty clear what the OP is asking

Comment: @brucesmitherson careful what you say, John Rennie has plenty of rep to downvote you to -300k :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a huge huge problem here.

You could be a Boltzmann brain. But to calculate the probability that you are a Boltzmann brain we have to have a theory about the way the universe is and then quantify how many Boltzmann brains that universe has compared to how many real brains it has.

But you want to compute a probability. The only way to compute a probability is to use some information. If you use the information available to your brain, then if you are a Boltzmann brain your information (the information you use to compute your probability) is factually wrong.

As an extreme example. Imagine a universe with just one Boltzmann brain that happens to be just like your brain is just right now. It might think it is in a universe with certain physical constants, a certain age, a certain number of forces and particles etcetera etcetera. But it could be completely completely wrong about absolutely everything. So the probabilities it computes are just meaningless. And the poor Boltzmann brain doesn't have access to better information so it is hopeless for the poor Boltzmann brain to do a better job.

But you are quite right that if you have a model that predicts many more Boltzmann brains like you in it than real brains like you in it then the agreement of the model with observations (information available to your brain) should not be taken as evidence that you are a real brain.

However, if the same model predicts vastly more Boltzmann brains super different than you (including Boltzmann brains that have totally wrong ideas about the universe) then the fact that you are one of the brains with correct ideas should mean something.

But each brain could try to imagine a universe where it's ideas are correct ideas. That is, in fact, what we do. We try to come up with models where the facts in our brains are correct. If we failed, that would be the true failure.

We could try science and have it not work. And it would be a cause for concern if that happened. And we might worry in that case that we are a Boltzmann brain. Or we could work hard to be the first physicist to make sense of a reality that is real. It is just pessimism versus optimism. Not really probability theory.

> But isn't it science to calculate probability?

Science involves making predictions and comparing them to observations in a way that is consistent with past observations. Good science does the predictions in a way that is related to how it explains past results. Probability comes from mathematics, not from science and probability just a big if-then. So you can learn something about an if by looking at the then.

> To take the probability of entropy decrease needed to fluctuate one brain then to take probability of entropy decrease needed to fluctuate visible universe

To compute a probability you need a sample space from which to draw. My point was where does the sample space come from. If the sample space comes from a brain, then Boltzmann brains with totally wrong opinions will draw up their own sample spaces and compute their own, wrong, probabilities based on the totally wrong sample spaces. You could have a universe with five forces that has a Boltzmann brain with your exact opinions including you thinking there are four forces. And your brain would have an opinion about what the visible universe looks like and it could be very very very wrong.

> and compare the two - to see how many BB one can fluctuate at the cost of one universe. I understand that it will be inaccurate by a huge factor still why not do it.

If you imagine that your brain's opinion are correct. And then you compute that if they are correct that the universe is full of many Boltzmann brains then you might reasonably wonder whether you are, in fact, a Boltzmann brain. However even if you computed how many Boltzmann brains there are like you given that there is one real brain like you that correctly sees the universe and is full of true facts. It doesn't really matter how big or small that ratio is. Because you have no idea the probability that there is a real brain like yours given that you are a Boltzmann brain.

There are possible universes with Boltzmann brains just like yours where there are zero real brains like yours throughout the entire space and time of that universe. So your opinions don't tell you the way the universe is.

If you tried to make sense of your opinions and failed, that is a good sign you are a Boltzmann brain. But it could be a sign that more work is needed.

And when I say Boltzmann brain I don't mean the run of the mill fluctuation of protons and neutrons and electrons that produce an actual physical brain that momentarily look like your brain does. I mean any self interacting system that makes perceptions of its own state the way your brain does. Any thing that feels like your brain does and has opinions like your brain does.

After all, you wanted to include simulations.

So that includes arrangements of weird stuff satisfying totally different laws. After all you can imagine a universe that follows our laws but fluctuates a brain that has a memory consistent with a totally Newtonian universe. So your opinions could be totally wrong opinions and a fluctuation in a vastly more complicated universe.

Your brain might not even be large enough to conceptualize even the most superficial description of the actual universe and so your computations of the probabilities of generating a brain like yours in a universe like that might be impossible. But even if it were possible there is no way to assign a sample space for having these different kinds of real universes.

Comment: But isn't it science to calculate probability? To take the probability of entropy decrease needed to fluctuate one brain then to take probability of entropy decrease needed to fluctuate visible universe and compare the two - to see how many BB one can fluctuate at the cost of one universe. I understand that it will be inaccurate by a huge factor still why not do it. I really find it hard to believe no one has done the calculation as meaningless as it might be.

Comment: Thanks Timaeus it took some time but I think I get it now.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the calculation is that it depends a lot on the underlying assumptions. Once you assume that Boltzmann brains are plausible, restricting the calculation to our brain structure and our current model of the universe seems absurd. What should be computed is the probability over all possible universes and all possible structures that give rise to consciousness. The problem is, that we cannot currently ever compute something more simple than that, which is the likelihood of our current universe, even is we restrict ourselves to computable universes (for general non-computable universes there is not even a meaningful measure of probability). For a more detailed discussion you can start with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_universe_hypothesis

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental problem here is well described [in this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0208013). You can step aside a bit from the assumptions made, the problem is a generic one. In any generic cosmological model, you'll get Poincaré recurrences and then the most likely ones will be where you exist as a Boltzmann brain like state. But this then causes predictions of your observations that violate our observations, because you'll be far more likely experience a far more random universe than we actually observe.

Answer (score 0):

If you believe [this paper by J. Richard Gott III](https://arxiv.org/abs/0802.0233) of Princeton University, you may rest a bit easier about your status as an ordinary observer in an inflating universe.

The paper calculates that most Boltzmann brains would last only an instant before vanishing.  It would be highly unlikely for an ordinary observer to find a Boltzmann brain that hung around long enough to take a [Turing test](http://www.turing.org.uk/scrapbook/test.html).  Even if the Boltzmann brain existed long enough to answer 20 questions in a row satisfactorily, it would be exponentially unlikely to continue its existence long enough to answer the 21st question.

The author writes: "How do I know that I am an ordinary observer, rather than just a BB with the same experiences...? Here is how: I will wait 10 seconds and see if I am still here. 1,
2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10. Yes I am still here. If I were a random BB with all the perceptions I had had up to the point where I said 'I will wait 10 seconds and see if I am still here'...then I would not be answering that next question or lasting those 10 extra seconds. BBs do not pass the Turing test for intelligent observers, so if I see one I should not regard it as an intelligent observer."

Boltzmann brains arise from random fluctuations in Gibbons-Hawking radiation in exponentially expanding de Sitter space.  But the author argues that Gibbons-Hawking thermal radiation is observer-dependent, so the only Boltzmann brains that could thermally fluctuate into existence could be observed, but could not observe.

The author acknowledges that observer-independent Boltzmann brains "could be created by quantum tunneling events, but the rate at which ordinary observers are being added to the universe by tunneling events to inflating regions exceeds the rate for producing BBs by tunneling by an infinite factor."

So, according to the paper, it's unlikely you are a Boltzmann brain.

The possibility that you are software fluctuating on a microchip seems to me philosophy rather than physics.  Nick Bostrom, a philosopher at Oxford, has a [website devoted to the computer simulation argument](http://www.simulation-argument.com).  You will find numerous links to other resources on his site.  Here is a link to his paper, ["Are You Living in a Computer Simulation?"](http://www.simulation-argument.com/simulation.html).

Comment: Please forgive me I must be a horrible case of dunning-Kruger. My understanding how such brain would work: Assuming that I am Boltzman brain, the world I am experiencing does not exist since my senses are deceiving me into believing that I am writing this answer to you. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_doubt) While in fact every letter of this sentence is written by a countless BB that have each fluctuated with my previous memories up to the point I pressed previous key. The memory of myself up to this point does not have to be human brain it could be anything including simulation.

Comment: So to calculate the probability I would need to take sum of all BB that I need to fluctuate into existence to experience my life, and compare it with probability of fluctuation of size of the universe. If one outweighs other by a huge factor it should be correct. And what I am looking for is some article where someone has done that calculation, since I am not physicist and bad with formulas.

Comment: @MatasVaitkevicius: You can't have the memories of countless BBs, because when each vanishes its memories vanish also.  Random fluctuations are not causally connected.  BBs arise because of the concept of infinite time. The denominator of the probability ratio is infinity. But so is the numerator.  Infinity / Infinity = Indeterminate (the result can't be 1).  Studies I've seen don't quantify probabilities; they compare probabilities.  For example, Gott wrote that it's infinitely more likely that random quantum fluctuations will produce ordinary observers than BBs, so you're not likely a BB.

Comment: Why can't I have memories of countless BBs, if I have infinite time to fluctuate all the brains with all the memories?

Comment: So when Boltzmann postulated BB he surely must have meat they were temporal since fluctuation only can happen for very short time (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_fluctuation) and energy must go back to 0. Even to have a single thought one would probably need more than one BB.

Comment: I agree with Matas. One stitches together different fluctuations with consistent memories. The only real question is whether our observations are consistent with being such BB.

Comment: @MatasVaitkevicius: Albrecht and Sorbo coined the term BB in 2004.  Here’s a link to a recent paper that may help you: http://www.pitt.edu/~jdnorton/Goodies/Boltzmann_Brain/Boltzmann_Brain.html.

Comment: @user1247: There would need to be a transcendent self to stitch together the memories of numerous non-causally connected BBs. In a high-enropy universe consisting of uniformly distributed Gibbons-Hawking radiation in equilibrium with itself, where would such a self reside, and how would it connect to the BBs?  The BB paradox is that if we are a BB with full-blown memories, how would we know?  The paper I linked in my comment to Matas may help resolve this paradox.  This is philosophy, not physics, IMO. :)

Comment: @Ernie, there would not need to be a "transcendent self," just a physicalist account of personal identity. This is clear by Star Trek transporter thought experiments...